# Heroku to AWS migration using React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a functioning React web application which is deployed on Heroku.  I am trying to migrate the entire application to AWS but I am running into some trouble.  I first tried to create an EC2 instance and clone my github repo there.  I couldn't get this to work.  I am thinking it is because only server side code should be added to an EC2 instance and not client side.

I am now trying to use Elastic Beanstalk to upload my code (server and client).  The process seems pretty straightforward however when I upload my .zip file and deploy I get the following error in the Event Log:

> Failed to find package.json. Node.js may have issues starting. Verify package.json is valid or place code in a file named server.js or app.js.

I have a `package.json` file in my zip folder so I'm really not sure what is going on here.  Any advice on this would be helpful.

Here are the contents of my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "beer",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.12",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.6.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.8.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.422.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "material-ui-rating": "^2.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^7.8.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.2",
    "session-middleware": "^1.0.2",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "client": "react-scripts start",
    "server": "nodemon --watch server server/server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

And the file structure inside my zip:

```
--beer
  -build
  -nodemodules
  -package.json
  -public
    -index.html
    -manifest.json
  -server
    -server.js
    -modules
    -routes
  -src
    -index.js
    -components
      -App
        -App.js
      -redux
        -reducers
          -index.js
        -sagas
          index.js
```

Comment: Is the `package.json` in the root of your zip folder?

Comment: @Chris I am not sure.  I don't have a root folder but I did try to mimic the format of the Elastic Beanstalk Demo folder.  The package.json is located in the main folder.

Comment: The root folder is your project's "top folder". If that's what you mean by "main folder" I think we're saying the same thing. Please [edit] your question and add the contents of your `package.json`.

Comment: @Chris I've edited my post to include the contents of my package.json

Comment: Hrm, that looks valid. Are there any other interesting messages in the deploy output?

Comment: @Chris I'm only getting the one error.  I am wondering if the issue is with how my file structure is laid out.  My github repo can be cloned and made to work without changing the structure though.

Comment: If you can show us your directory structure and location of key files that might help.

Comment: @Chris I edited my post and tried to outline the important files within the structure.  In the Elastic Beanstalk documentation I found this "Not include a parent folder or top-level directory (subdirectories are fine)" . I don't think I have a parent folder or top-level directory but I am not certain.

Comment: Oh, then your top level `beer/` directory shouldn't exist in your zip file. How did you create your zip? What operating system are you on?

Comment: @Chris I am using a Mac.  I basically just found the location of my project folder and compressed it.  I'm not really sure how I would zip multiple files without putting them in a folder.

Comment: Basically, you select them all and then compress them. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html#using-features.deployment.source.gui

Comment: @Chris It looks like zipping the folders the way you recommended removes the error that I posted.  However my Elastic Beanstalk still has the 'Degraded' health status, only now there is no error explaining why :(

Comment: Okay, that's good. I'll add a proper answer. Please check your [runtime logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html) (this is different from the deploy log) and see what they say. Feel free to ask another question if you find something there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying to Elastic Beanstalk with a zip file you must ensure that your [zip doesn't contain a top-level container directory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html). In your case, your `beer/` directory can't be included.

On macOS or Windows you can [select the contents of your `beer/` directory and compress them](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html#using-features.deployment.source.gui). If you upload a new zip without a top-level directory, Elastic Beanstalk should be able to find your `package.json` file and deploy your application properly.